# Understanding the Date class

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

In Javascript/Nodejs I typed `x=new Date(2010,0,1)` This will mean 1st Jan 2010. But I see `2009-12-31T18:30:00.000Z` in the output. What could be the reason for that?
[image]

Comment: `2009-12-30T18:30:00.000Z` is the ISO datetime format. You can read about the whole `Date` object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing parameters hour, minute and second are initialised to `0`, the entire date is assumed to be your timezone (2010-01-01 00:00:00 India time I assume), and the result you see is being output as UTC date. In other words, when it was midnight Jan 1st 2010 in your timezone, it was Dec. 31st 18:30 UTC.

Why it's being output in UTC depends on your method of printing and/or browser used; it's somewhat free to choose how it will output the date.

Comment: Could you also provide a short hint why `x.getMilliseconds()` is returning 0?

Comment: Because why shouldn't it? The millisecond part of the date has been initialised as `0` as well.

Comment: Got it. I was thinking it will show the milliseconds from the epoch till now. I found a different function which gets this output `getTime()`